# Unity tweak tool does no change on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, themes, icons, unity-tweak-tool

I've done a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to install Unity Tweak Tool right after updating my packages. At the first run, I've managed to change my theme and my icons, but after rebooting my machine, all the configurations that I changed were ignored and the default theme and icons of Ubuntu were loaded. After that, I can only see my modified themes and icons if I run nautilus on super user mode or running the following commands:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

But as soon as I restart my machine, these settings are gone.

I tried to find a solution to this and found many topics related to configurations that could be done with the dconf editor, but none of them did me any good. I also tried purging Unity Tweak Tool, cleaning the cache and  reinstalling it from the software center, but at the end it didn't change a thing. The gnome tweak tool also cannot change my theme or icons.

Can someone give me a light on what is happening here ?

Comment: Did you run it using `sudo`?

Comment: I did, but nothing changed.

Comment: What is the output of `stat -c %U ~/.config`?

Comment: Here is the output:   asus

Comment: What is the output of `stat -c %U ~/.config ~/.compiz/ ~/.local/ ~/.local/share/ ~/.config/compiz-1/` ? Is there anywhere `root`?

Comment: It just says "asus" 5 times, no root.

Comment: By the way, "asus" is my username in this machine.

Comment: Use `sudo chown -R $USER ~/` to reset the permission at check if you can now change the themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a workaround myself (It is not the way I wanted, but is the way it works).

I manually moved the default theme (Ambiance) folder from /usr/share/themes to another folder in order to have a backup, and made a copy of the folder of my desired theme (which is supposed to be in /usr/share/themes, as long as you installed it) with the same name of the default.

For example, assuming that my default theme right now is the Ambiance theme (Default ubuntu 14.04 theme) and I want to use the Ambiance-Flat-Blue-Pro theme, I execute the following commands:

```
cd /usr/share/themes
sudo mv Ambiance ~/Documents/
sudo cp -R Ambiance-Flat-Blue-Pro/ Ambiance
sudo reboot
```

The same works for icons, but instead of making modifications in the /usr/share/themes/, you just need to do it on the /usr/share/icons/ folder.